# EF4 - C# Sorting using lambda expression

Tags: entity-framework-4, lambda, sql-order-by

In SQL I can write

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM master_table a
LEFT JOIN detail_table b ON (b.a_id = a.id)
ORDER BY a.id, b.order_field
```

Is it possible to do the same with EF4 ?
I cannot understand how to specify order by clause.
So far I tried

```
List<master_table> l = context.master_table.Include("detail_table").
OrderBy(x=>x.id).
ThenBy( //here is the problem, y=>y.detail_table.order_filed doesn't compile, 
//y=>y.detail_tables.OrderBy(z=>z.order_field) - throws a run-time exception
).
ToList();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax in LINQ to Entities can be similar to your SQL query:

```
var result = from a in context.master_table
             join b in context.detail_table on a.id equals b.a_id
             orderby a.id, b.order_field
             select new { /*...*/};
```

**Edit:**

With the clarification from your comment - The problem is that in the SQL query you have pairs of items that you are joining (a,b) - while in the Linq to Entities query you are trying to do you want a secondary order by a *navigation property*.

The difference is that there's a one to many relationship between the `master_table` entries and the `detail_table` entries in this context, you have a grouping by `master_table` entry already - given that it doesn't make sense (to the compiler or in general) to be able to express that sort order on the `detail_table` level.

I would just enforce it when you enumerate the results - the `master_table` entries are already in the right order, just return the details  using `foo.detail_tables.OrderBy(x=>x.order_field)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not exactly what I wanted... I might have expressed myself unclear. I want to get a list of `master_table` entities including details(`detail_table`) which are sorted by `order_field`. Maybe I'm trying to do something impossible.

Comment: @a1ex07: How does this LINQ query not match your original SQL query example?  It looks like an exact match to me.

Comment: Thanks for extra explanations